# Read from input in a declaration in C++?

Tags: c++, input

So I'm coming from Java where you can do something like this when using a Scanner

```
int n = s.nextInt();
```

Now that I'm dabbling with C++, I find it annoying to do:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
```

Is there a shorthand way to read from input in a variable declaration?

Comment: How short do you require

Comment: Do spaces count in your shorthand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just make a helper function to do this for you:

```
// Using an anonymous namespace, since this is intended to
// be just an internal utility for your file... it's not
// a super awesome, shareable API (especially since it hard
// codes the use of std::cin and has no error checking).
namespace {

// Helper function that reads an integer from std::cin.
// As pointed out in Robin's solution, you can use a template
// to handle other types of input, as well.
int ReadInt() {
  int result;
  std::cin >> result;
  return result;
}
}
```

Then you can do:

```
int n = ReadInt();
```

If you want to really go all out, though, you can create a more elaborate solution:

```
namespace input_utils {
class IOException {};
class Scanner {
  public:
     Scanner() : input_(std::cin) {}
     Scanner(std::istream& input) : input_(input) {}

     template<typename T> T Read() {
       CheckStreamOkay();
       T result;
       input_ >> result;
       CheckStreamOkay();
       return result;
     }

  private:
     void CheckStreamOkay() {
       if (!input_) {
         throw IOException();
       }
     }
     std::istream& input_;
};
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
input_utils::Scanner scanner(std::cin);
int a = scanner.Read<int>();
int b = scanner.Read<int>();
double c = scanner.Read<double>();
...
```

Though, at that point, you might want to look for an existing library that already does this.

Comment: To emulate the Java behavior, you should throw an exception on failure. Or you should at least have *some* way to indicate a failure here.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley if we're really going for emulating Java behavior, then we should have a wrapper "Scanner" class, and it should take an arbitrary "std::istream" as an input, not strictly std::cin. I agree with what you're saying, but the OP was asking simply about the simplicity of the syntax (and the example given did not do any checking, either). This immediately addresses the OPs pain point, but you're right that this would require a lot of improvement to make into a good API.

Comment: Nice full example putting these answers together. +1

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in shortcut for this, but you could certainly make your own function for this:

```
int read_int() {
    int res;
    cin >> res;
    return res;
}
...
int a = read_int();
```

Answer (score 3):

Making the functions suggested by dasblinkenlight and Michael Aaron Safyan more generic using templates (now incorporated into final example of Michael's answer):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> T read();

template<typename T>
T read<T>() {
    T ret;
    std::cin >> ret;
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    int i = read<int>();
    double d = read<double>();
    std::cout << i << std::endl << d;
    return 0;
}
```